# Centreon Tickets

Tags: html, scroll, centos

Necesito ayuda. Resulta que al crear el widget de Centreon-Tickets, me aparece de esta forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que en vez de que aparezcan solo 3 servicios de un hosts, aparezcan más y quitar el scroll.
He visto que en la demo de Centreon, no tienen este problema, en el apartado de Open Tickets. Esta opción está en Home, Custom Views, pinchando en Open Tickets.
[Demo Centreon](https://demo.centreon.com/centreon/main.php?p=103)

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Versión Centreon 18.10.2.
Versión Centreon Tickets 19.04.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.